# ubuntu 16.4 install qgis error

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, qgis

install steps:

- add: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main
- add: deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt-get install qgis

then got errors:

```
Setting up libqgis-gui3.4.6 (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
Setting up qgis-providers (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: _ZN6kmldom15SerializePrettyB5cxx11ERKN5boost13intrusive_ptrINS_7ElementEEE
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up libqgis-analysis3.4.6 (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
Setting up libqgis-app3.4.6 (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
Setting up libqgis-customwidgets (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
Setting up libqgis-server3.4.6 (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
Setting up libqgisgrass7-3.4.6 (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
Setting up libqgispython3.4.6 (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
Setting up python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit (5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4) ...
Setting up python3-qgis-common (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
Setting up python3-qgis (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
Setting up libjs-leaflet (1.0.3+dfsg-1~xenial0) ...
Setting up qgis-common (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up qgis-plugin-grass-common (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up qgis-provider-grass (3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 3.4.6+dfsg-1~xenial1); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Experimented a lot of installation methods are not successful, who has encountered how to solve, thank you

Comment: hi! you're doing the install wrong the way I see it. you migh also want to first switch to ubuntu 19.04 as on it qgis is in the repos and you do not need add ppas. you just need to type `sudo apt-get install qgis python-matplotlib python-scipy  python3-qgis qgis-plugin-grass` but I guess that won't work on ubunu 16.04

Comment: Hi @tatsu,thanks for your comment，but our company us Ubuntu 16.04